# I cant add the Input Decorator in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm getting data from father component with Input in Angular, but it doen't work

My child:

```js
export class ForumComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id_foro: number = 3;

  nombre: string = '';
  desc: string = ''
  
  forum = this.forumService.getById(this.id_foro).subscribe((data: Forum[]) => {
    this.nombre = data[0].name
    this.desc = data[0].description
  });
  
  
  constructor(private forumService: ForumService) { }
```

where I call it:

```html
<div *ngIf="forum.id_category_fk === category.id">
     <app-forum [id_foro]="forum.id"></app-forum>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to call the method and assign the value.

For your scenario, you should call the service method in `ngOnInit()`.

```js
export class ForumComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id_foro: number = 3;

  ...
  
  forum: Forum;
  
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.forumService.getById(this.id_foro).subscribe((data: Forum[]) => {
      this.nombre = data[0].name;
      this.desc = data[0].description;
      
      this.forum = data[0];
    });
  }

}
```